# jQuery append reference to added element

Tags: jquery, append, dom-manipulation

I've got a data set that's retrieved by an ajax call, i'm looping over the data set and for each item in the set append a `<li>` to a list that's on the page.

how can I get a hold of the appended listitem in the each-loop so I can also perform individual actions on that

```
var myData = getData();
var list = $('#list');
$.each(myData, function(index, person){
    list.append('<li>'+person.name+'</li>');
    // On the just appended <li> element I want to set the data-person attribute

    //var listitem = ???;
    //listitem.data('person', person);
});
```

Here's a fiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pcLt7/1/

Comment: Can't you just set it straight away, `list.append('<li data-person="">'+person.name+'</li>');`?

Comment: @smilledge This will only work if "person" is serializeable. And it's nasty when it's large.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Sorry, I though you just wanted to store single string attributes. For things like this you might want to look at a framework like Backbone.js.

Comment: @smilledge I'm not the OP. There are always multiple ways of doing something and concatenating a data-attribute is not one of the beauty ones.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just create a jQuery object from the raw HTML and then append that

```
var listitem = $('<li>'+person.name+'</li>');
list.append(listitem);
listitem.data('person', person);
```

Note: It's not a good idea to do DOM manipulation inside a loop.

If the number of elements is small then just use my solution. If this could be hundreds of elements, you may want to work on detached nodes by using detach on the list before adding the items and later adding it to the DOM again.

Don't optimize prematurely. The solution uses less code and is more readable than any other and works just fine.

Comment: Agreed. It would be better to build a string of all the `<li>` items, including the data- attributes, and when done append the entire thing to the paren #list element.

Comment: But using the data-attribute is not the same. You can't put a reference in their.

Comment: Having a reference inthere isn't a requirement, i was building the element including the data-person attribute at first but JSON.stringify is rather flackey when it comes to escaping quotes which results in alot of broken HTML attributes/elements. How would you solve that?

Comment: But using a reference is nice. Why stringify the JSON on the server, then parse it on the client, just to stringify it again and let jQuery parse it once more?

Comment: @Prinzhorn check this fiddle and click on the last item ... that's a situation causing problems, that's why I'd prefer using the data method over just writing out the data attributes in a string. http://jsfiddle.net/kHCFB/1/

Comment: @ChrisR If the number of elements is small then just use my solution. If this could be hundreds of elements, you may want to work on detached nodes by using `detach` on the list before adding the items and later adding it to the DOM again.

Comment: @Prinzhorn => Well it's a relatively small list but could potentially grow when a user decides to expand many nodes deep (i'm building a ajax loaded tree-like system). In normal usecases i'm talking 30-40 dom elements, in edgecases mayby 200-300 ... but not all at once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17413/discussion-between-chrisr-and-prinzhorn)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Based on [Prinzhorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422124/prinzhorn) suggestion ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12675490/605154)):

> Note: It's not a good idea to do DOM manipulation inside a loop

I have  changed my code.. now i am concatenating the "li" in one string and then adding all of them together to the list

```
 var list = $('#list');
var str = "";
$.each(myData, function(index, person){
    str += "<li data-person='" + JSON.stringify(person) + "'>"
    + person.name + "</li>";

    // On the just appended <li> element I want to set the data-person attribute

    //var listitem = ???;
    //listitem.data('person', person);
});

list.append(str);
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/pcLt7/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/pcLt7/4/)

Comment: i'm not a fan of manually serializing my objects, i'd rather use JSON.stringify but that causes problems with single quotes (see the last list item here: http://jsfiddle.net/kHCFB/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(myData, function(index, person){
    list.append('<li data-person="'+person.name+'"+ data-member="'+person.member+'">'+person.name+'</li>');
});

$('#list li').click(function(){
    var person = $(this).data('person');
    var member = $(this).data('member');
    alert(person + ' is ' + (member ? 'a' : 'no') + ' member');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gV9RJ/

Answer (score 1):

In a single go

```
$.each(myData, function(index, person){
    $('<li/>', {
        text: person.name,
        data: person
      }).appendTo(list);
});
```